# Drupal confusion when including multiple instances of same webform on a page

Tags: 7, forms, theming, webforms

I have nearly the same problem than this : [Multiple forms on single page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6202/multiple-forms-on-single-page)

But the answer  is for an inclusion on a **page** template and I want to do the same on a **node** template where I can't use any incremental ID loop. I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

In either [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) or a `node template` just call the forms using `drupal_get_form` each form will given a unique `build_id` and there should be no problem displaying any number of forms on the page.

`hook_forms` in this answer https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/6230/3279 has nothing to do with your question. You don't need to worry about incremental form IDs or anything.

Here is an example of how to use a preprocess function for a Node (type):
http://purencool.com/drupal-7-preprocess-tutorial-adding-variable-to-template this uses this Drupal API function https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7

Your code would look something like (this is example code not guarenteed to work):

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if ($vars['node']->type == 'MY_NODE_TYPE') {
    // link to webform paths.
    $vars['custom_form_links'] = implode(' ', array(l('Please Fillout Form 1', 'some/path/to/webform'), l('Please Fillout Form 2', 'some/path/to/webform2')));
    // Or just embed the forms.
    $form1 = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('myform1'));
    $form2 = drupal_render(drupal_get_form('myform2'));
    $vars['custom_forms_embed'] = $form1 . $form2; // You may want additional HTML wrappers, figure it out.
  }
}
```

Then in your themes template files for like `node--YOURCONTENTTYPE.tpl.php` you echo these new variables.

Display Suite makes all this a ton easier with `Code Fields`, or custom fields, and dynamic `view_modes` so you don't need to touch template files either ...

None of this code is guarenteed to run -- it's just a rough example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get your form on template if you know their ids.

```
$form1 = drupal_get_form('form1_id');
$form2 = drupal_get_form('form2_id');
```

And then render by drupal_render()

```
drupal_render($form1);
drupal_render($form2);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but I want to add each form at the bottom of a type of node. Each form is linked with the title of the node. So I have to code it in my node template one time and it will add the SAME form at the end of each node. So for example with a view, I will have multiple same form on my page but all are linked with the first node.

Comment: @cocoggu, you should update your question with information on comment, as other people might not read full comment of each answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Panels module. You can embed any number of webforms in a single page using panels module. Create a custom page and add existing nodes as content

Comment: Thank you but I think I have poorly explain my problem, see my comment on Shuaib Nawaz answer